# Failed to enable NFS on Yocto Lilnux

Tags: yocto, nfs

I'm trying to enable NFS on a Linux image built using Yocto. The image is running on a dev board - Qualcomm RB5. After booting up, mount.nfs didn't seem to work, complaining

```
mount.nfs: No such device
```

When I check using dmesg | grep nfs, I got the following info but can't figure out myself what's the reason for the failure

```
[    7.323526] systemd[597]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.326328] request_module fs-nfsd succeeded, but still no fs?
[    7.337908] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    7.338655] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    7.346027] systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    7.346754] systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    7.454332] systemd[649]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.459122] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    7.460157] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    8.235626] systemd[726]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.241962] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    8.243164] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I check using "`systemctl status proc-fs-nfsd.mount`", it shows the following:

```
Jan 01 06:55:40 qrb5165-rb5 mount[1377]: mount: /proc/fs/nfsd: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'.
```

which is confusing since I thought I enabled nfs.

I made sure I enabled NFS support in local.conf. The following are the lines that I used to enable NFS:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " nfs"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "nfs-server"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "nfs-client"
```

Anything that I missed?

Comment: mount: /proc/fs/nfsd: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'   -   This error in my case was caused by inability to run nfs inside a VPS using OpenVz virtualization.    You need a VPS with KVM or VMWARE virtualization to make an NFS server in Docker work.  Same goes for Docker Swarm, also doesn't work in OpenVz (well, depends on your provider but mine had the kernel modules locked down)

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of digging, I just got NFS to work on the device. The failure was caused by a newbie error that I **haven't enabled NFS filesystem support in the kernel** so there was no corresponding kernel driver being built. I guess I somehow assumed Yocto will do that for you, but actually it will not.. I added the following changes to the kernel config to enable NFS on the device:

```
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFSD=y
```

Comment: Just to make your answer clearer, you may want to include what operating system this was on, and what file you added those lines to.  Also did you need to restart something ?